# Is there a Go framework or package that provides canned user authentication support?

Tags: authentication, go

I've gotten pretty spoiled by the mature frameworks available in Python (Django/Flask), so as I'm starting to learn Go, I have to wonder if there are any similar frameworks already in existence in Go to django.contrib.auth or Flask-Login?

The main use case is to handle simple user authentication and be able to extend it to accommodate some permissions-based routing within the app.

Comment: revel has twitter/facebook samples to authenticate => http://robfig.github.com/revel/samples/index.html

Comment: How production ready is revel?

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I found this Revel a while back and look rather interesting. That's why I made it a comment instead of answer. But Revel does have a lot of commits. I guess you should ask author?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As far as I know, there are not.  The closest out-of-the-box authentication you can probably get is via Google AppEngine, where the [user](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/reference)'s Google account can be retrieved and certain paths can be scoped for app [administrators only](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Secure_URLs).

In a standard Go web server, you will generally need to roll your own auth, but it's not as difficult as it sounds.  Many frameworks isolate you from decisions which are actually quite important; in typical Go fashion, you'll need to make these decisions based on the needs of your app, and then pick the existing libraries that are right for you.

## Login page

Wherever you need your users to log in, you will probably use an HTML form.  These will typically be rendered using the [html/template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package.  To retrieve the values when the form is submitted, use [request.FormValue](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue).

## Database

There are a number of ways to store user information; on the filesystem with [os](http://golang.org/pkg/os/) or in a SQL database using [database/sql](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/).  There are mature drivers for some NoSQL databases as well, including [MongoDB](http://labix.org/mgo) and [Redis](http://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis).

## Passwords

To compute and compare hashes to passwords, you'll want to use a preexisting mechanism so that you don't have to reinvent it yourself.  For this, the [go.crypto](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto) subrepository provides a [bcrypt](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt) package.

## Sessions

If you want to store session data, you can use a solution like [gorilla/sessions](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/sessions).  Based on your security needs, you can store the session data directly in a (optionally [secured](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/securecookie)) cookie or you can store it in a backend an only store a session ID in the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

From the READ.me

```
Allows your Martini application to support user login via an OAuth 2.0 backend.
```

https://github.com/martini-contrib/oauth2